# How to use aliases defined in the SELECT clause in the WHERE clause in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, alias

I made this query :

```
SELECT num_aula, tipo_aula, min(abs(250-capienza) as x
FROM aula
join (
select num_aula, tipo_aula
from aula
minus
select num_aula, tipo_aula
from occr_lezione
WHERE trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) >= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'lunedi'))
AND   trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) <= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'venerdi'))
AND to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24:mi') = '08:30'
AND Nome_sede = 'Centro Direzionale'
AND Giorno_lezione = 1)
using(num_aula,tipo_aula)
WHERE rownum = 1
AND   tipo_aula = 'Laboratorio'
AND   x < 10
group by num_aula, tipo_aula;
```

As you can see in the where clause I have " x < 10 " which raises a "not a valid identifier" error. How is that? If is not possible to do so, is there a way to access to a aggregate functions columns in the where of a select statement?

I've tried this :

```
With x as(
SELECT num_aula, tipo_aula, min(abs(250-capienza)) minimo
FROM aula
join (
select num_aula, tipo_aula
from aula
minus
select num_aula, tipo_aula
from occr_lezione
WHERE trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) >= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'lunedi'))
AND   trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) <= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'venerdi'))
AND to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24:mi') = '08:30'
AND Nome_sede = 'Centro Direzionale'
AND Giorno_lezione = 1)
using(num_aula,tipo_aula)
group by num_aula, tipo_aula)
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE rownum = 1
AND   x.tipo_aula = 'Aula'
AND   x.minimo < 15;
```

Is this worse then the having clause suggested?

Still have a problem to solve:

If I use the HAVING statement I have to do a comparison in the clause such as:

```
HAVING min(abs(250-capienza)) < > = <> something
```

And if I don't use it I can't access to the column I'm interested in.

Then what should I do if I want to select the row with the minimum value **without** comparing it to something ?

Comment: "Thank you for your time gentlemen." .... just a reminder, not all of us are of the male persuasion! *{;-)

Comment: oh my gosh, you're absolutely right @Boneist

Comment: The last dilemma is consuming me.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
 AND   x < 10
```

Use having clause after group by :

```
 HAVING min(abs(250-capienza)) < 10
```

Comment: I'd just note that here and in the original code, you'd need two right parens after `capienza` not just one.

Comment: ok, just discovered that the having clause is made exactly for this purpouse. The more you know ! Thanks @SMA

Comment: ty @justinCave it was only an error caused by the copy to be honest :)

Answer (score 2):

Row level filters are applied before doing the "PROJECT" operation (selecting certain columns). This is why you can't use column aliases in the same `WHERE` clause. You would have to wrap your query inside another `SELECT` statement and apply the condition to that.

```
SELECT * from ( 
/*... SELECT my_column as x  ... */
)
where x < 10
```